# some responses are "null" when making Batch Requests, but they are all independent queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-processing

I am making batch Graph API GET requests per the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

About half of them are coming back null, for e.g.:

```
[
   null,
   null,
   ...
   null,
 ],
 [
    {
      "body": <result json for a successful batch query>,
      "headers": ...etc.
```

Each GET request is:

- **independent**, a.k.a. I am not using JSONPath or trying to use the result of one of the batch requests in another batch request.
- has it's own access_token specified
- I am supplying a fallback access_token for the batch http API request.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you run the requests not in a batch, can you verify they return the correct result (i.e. if you run them individually)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Facebook batch API request sometime returns nulls?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9280741/why-does-facebook-batch-api-request-sometime-returns-nulls)

Comment: I voted to close this as a dup of a question asked a bit later because that question had a bit more info in it, and you are both asking the same thing.

Comment: If two people are asking the same thing, maybe Facebook introduced a bug into the api.  Have you check the bugs?

Comment: @stantonk, I just filed a bug for this.  Can you please vote it up? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295201867209494

Comment: @JohnnyO Ok, I just voted it up.

Comment: Btw, I'm working on a python API wrapper for facebook that includes support for Batch and FQL, see: https://bitbucket.org/sproutsocial/pyfaceb

Comment: Just to confirm, I am experiencing the same thing as @JohnnyO, I can run the batch queries again moments later and they all are returned correctly.

Comment: @stantonk, can you specify that you can reproduce the problem at Facebook's bug tracker?  I don't think that commenting on it is enough to vote it up and it still lists me as the only person who can reproduce it.  Thx.

Comment: Another bug in fb bug tracker that reports null on batch api requests: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/186195978183379?browse=search_50945fb90718c9c76576008

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble is that you did not see:

> You can force the server to include the output for the parent
>   operation even if it executed successfully by specifying
>   "omit_response_on_success":false in the parent request operation.

on [batch doc page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)

Comment: This isn't the issue. I am making **independent** batch requests. The "omit_response_on_success" only applies for **dependent** batch requests, in which an earlier (in the batch) request's result is referenced in a later request, via JSONPath.

This bug is reproducible and is referenced on Facebook's bug tracker in the above link in the comments under the original question.